# working with void for the first time

Tags: c++

I've recently started messing around with void and ran into a problem

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void smallSort();

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    cout << "Please enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Please enter the third number" << endl;
    cin >> num3;
    cout << "Now I will sort from smallest to biggest!" << endl;

    smallSort();
    return 0;
}

void smallSort(int& num1, int& num2, int& num3){
    if(num1 > num2)
        swap(num1, num2);
    if(num1 > num3)
        swap(num1, num3);
    if(num2 > num3)
        swap(num2, num3);

    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << endl;
}
```

I've tried to add parameters into the smallSort within the main but it says that there's too many arguments.  I've also tried removing the parameters from the void but that didn't work either.  Any tips or anything I can read would be great, thanks

Comment: If you have arguments in a function, you actually need to pass the arguments when calling the function. Also note that since you're programming C++, the functions `void smallSort()` and `void smallSort(int& num1, int& num2, int& num3)` are *not* the same function. Read more about function overloading. Actually, the first is equal to `void smallSort(void)` (i.e. a function taking *no* arguments).

Comment: Further note that since you declare a `smallSort` function taking no arguments, and calling a `smallSort` taking no arguments, you don't get a compiler error, instead you get a *linker* error saying that `smallSort` is undefined. And it it, because you don't define a `smallSort` function taking no arguments. And this is the point where you should look for and read about the difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*.

Comment: Get the `cout` out of the function (a function should be a function). Move it to after the call to `smallSort()`. This is a programming principle. It will not fix your current problem, but it will make your life easier. For example with the `cout` where it is, you can refactor by removing the `&`s (removing the `&` will have no behavioural affect.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `void smallSort()` is the usual way to declare a function with no parameters in C++. The alternative form `void smallSort(void)` is permitted only for compatibility with C.

Comment: If you're asking about a compile-time error message, include the exact message in the question rather than just describing it. In this case the problem is obvious enough that it doesn't make much difference, but the exact wording of the message can be critical.

Comment: it says too many arguments in void smallSort

Answer (score 4):

Your function definition doesn't match its declaration:

```
void smallSort(); // <== zero args
void smallSort(int& num1, int& num2, int& num3){ // <== three args
```

Those have to match precisely. Your declaration should be changed to:

```
void smallSort(int&, int&, int&);
```

Also you're not actually *calling* `smallSort` with any arguments:

```
smallSort();
```

should be:

```
smallSort(num1, num2, num3);
```

Comment: It is just the first bit (the declaration), that caused the problems. Every thing else leads out of that. E.g to many arguments error.

Comment: The call is part of everything else. It leads out of first error. It also leads to the too many arguments compiler-error.

Comment: yeah this didn't fix my problem

Comment: if i take out the arguments from the void it says that num1-3 weren't declared.  is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @cppfan It should look like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4419ff5085f4691). I added comments for the two issues in your code.

Comment: ahh thank you barry.  i didn't know you had to change it above the main that was my problem.  thanks again