# Surface Area / Volume

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get this code to work to calculate surface area and volume of a box.  It compiles but doesn't output the correct data.  I think maybe the problem is within the void Box:: parts but have hit a wall.  Or it could be the Height = Height but I couldn't get it to run without error any other way.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Box.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Box box;
    double boxHeight, boxWidth, boxLength;

    cout << "This program will tell you the surface area and volume of a box" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the height " << endl;
    cin >> boxHeight;
    cout << "Please enter the width " << endl;
    cin >> boxWidth;
    cout << "Please enter the length" << endl;
    cin >> boxLength;

    box.setHeight();

    cout << "The surface area is " << box.getSurfaceArea() << endl;
    cout << "The volume is " << box.getVolume() << endl;


    return 0;
}

void Box::setHeight(){
    if(Height< 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Height = Height;
    }


void Box::setLength(){
   if(Length< 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Length = Length;
    }


void Box::setWidth(){
   if(Width< 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Width = Width;
    }


double Box::getSurfaceArea(){

    return 2*(Length*Width) + 2*(Length*Height) + 2*(Width + Height);
}



double Box::getVolume(){

    return Length*Width*Height;
}
```

And the hpp file is this:

```
#ifndef BOX_HPP_INCLUDED
#define BOX_HPP_INCLUDED

class Box
{
public:
    void setHeight();
    void setWidth();
    void setLength();
    double getVolume();
    double getSurfaceArea();

private:
    double Length;
    double Width;
    double Height;
};


#endif
```

Comment: How do you think your `set` methods will correctly set anything if you don't provide a value for them to set? For example `setHeight()`: what will that call set the height to?

Comment: As a side note there's a small mistake in your `getSurfaceArea`.

Comment: You made the exact same mistake [a week prior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28257307/560648)...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to pass the values you want to set in your setters:

```
void setHeight(double height);
void setWidth(double width);
void setLength(double length);

void Box::setHeight(double height)
{
    if(height < 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Height = height;
}

void Box::setWidth(double width)
{
    if(width < 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Width = width;
}

void Box::setLength(double length)
{
    if(length < 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Length = length;
}
```

Also, you need to set not only the height, but the width and the length of the box:

```
box.setHeight(boxHeight);
box.setWidth(boxWidth);
box.setLength(boxLength);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: All three of your `if` conditions are wrong. You must test the argument for non-negativity.

Answer (score 1):

```
box.setHeight();
```

Think about how exactly you're telling this box to set its height. More specifically, *what* it should set its height to. Generally, you would tell it something like:

```
box.setHeight (h);
```

where `h` is the height you want to set it to. That means passing in a parameter to a function that would look something like:

```
void Box::setHeight(double newH){
    if(newH < 0)
        cout << "Error.  Must enter a positive number " << endl;
    else
        Height = newH; // assuming Height is a member variable.
    }
}
```

The way you have it at the moment:

```
Height = Height;
```

simply leaves the height at whatever value it had previously.

Ditto for the other two dimensions as well, of course.

---

Just one other thing I'd like to mention, it's unusual for a class to actually print something to indicate a problem since that's usually something the caller should decide. You don't want your application output screwed up by a general purpose class outputting information.

It would probably be better to return an error code or throw an exception and let the caller decide what to do. Or maybe even silently use the absolute value of the parameter with something like:

```
if (val < 0) val = -val;
Height = val;
```

Although some will argue that violates the principle of least astonishment, it really depends on what you consider to be the best behaviour.

It may be okay in this circumstance because a cube will still have the same surface area and volume regardless of how it's oriented or located in space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values user enters, are never able to reach the private members of the class. You must provide a argument in your methods `setHeight` `setWidth` to actually set the private members `Height` and `Width` (and similar for length too).

In you current code, you do not provide a constructor so you are actually dealing with garbage values of private members Height, Width and Length.

Edit: Your constructor in the `public` of hpp file should look like:

```
Box()
{
Height=0;
Width=0;
Length=0;
}
```

Comment: so i should add a Box() in the public of the hpp file?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, you should create your box after inputting dimensions using a constructor (with height, width and length as parameters) and initialize your data members  within this constructor.

Comment: Yes. It will be a good idea to add a constructor to initialize all the data members to zero. So that even if u accidently use them Without providing them with values later in your code, you dont actually use garbage values.

Comment: Alright I did that but then got back an error "no matching function for call to 'Box::Box()"

Comment: beat you to it haha.  i just figured that out.  thanks for your help akshay

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your approach because the value entered by user are not available to set functions so simply you are initializing the dimension with garbage so either use argumented set function like setHeight(int height) or restructure the program so that it does not require the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `set` functions don't set anything:

- If their corresponding member variable is below `0`, they do nothing.
- Else, they assign their corresponding member variable back to itself, aka do nothing.

---

You want to tell the `set` functions **what** they should set their value to.

For example if you want to tell "set the width to 100", there's an important piece of information missing in a call like `setWidth();` — It doesn't know that you want to set the width to 100.

Why?

Because you didn't tell it. You want to pass that information to your `set` functions somehow. And *function parameters* are there for that:

`void setWidth(int NewWidth)` declares the `setWidth` to accept an `int` as a parameter.

Now you can call it like this: `setWidth(100)` and it will know that you want to set the width to 100. Or you can do:

```
int width;
cin >> width;
box.setWidth(width);
```

to ask the value for `width` from the user.

---

Then the only thing left for you now is to use that function parameter variable in your function body to check if `NewWidth` is below zero, or else, assign `NewWidth` to `Width`.

Comment: id rather have the user enter it for easier functionality.  any tip for fixing that?

Comment: @cppfan Variables can be used to accomplish that: `int height; cin >> height; setHeight(height);`

Comment: @cppfan Added that to my answer.

Comment: Also my example uses `int` but you probably want to use `double` instead.